# Icon not displaying in flutter

Tags: flutter, svg, icons

Ok, so I'm trying to implement a custom icon in flutter but it's not rendering the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2hsu.png)

Font code:

```
fonts:
      family: icon
      fonts:
            asset: assets/fonts/MyFlutterApp.ttf
```

Icon code:

```
icon: new Icon(const IconData(0xe800, fontFamily: 'icon'))
```

Comment: how is your assets folder structure ? try flutter clean + hot restart also.

Comment: Alr tried all of that

Comment: I had this problem, because FlutterIcon was not detecting/rendering properply my svg custom icon. Did you check how it was previewed on FlutterIcon website ??